# Heading of tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

How can I align the heading so that it doesn't exceed the width of the table and the text?  I would actually have wanted the headline to be printed one line down if it was too long... any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Hello}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello \textellipsis}\\ \midrule
    \textbf{Hello} & \textellipsis Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello\\ \midrule
    \textbf{Hello} & \textellipsis Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello\\      \midrule
    \textbf{Hello} & \textellipsis Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello\\ \midrule
    \textbf{Hello} & \textellipsis Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello\\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have specified `c` which is single line.  use `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}` or `>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X`

Comment: If I want to center the whole heading, would it be O.K. to enter the command `\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering Hello}`? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher -- Give replacing `c` with `>{\centering}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}` a try.

Comment: @Mico Would it make a difference if I left `\relax` out like @DavidCarlisle?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher - David Carlisle is infinitely more knowledgeable in these matters than I am. I therefore think you should ask him directly.

Comment: @Schubladenzieher no but if you have to ask you should add it:-)

Comment: @Schubladenzieher in general a `\dimexpr` is ended once it hits `\relax` (and that `\relax` is then removed from input), or once it hits something that can't be a part of an expression. If you don't know what exactly follows the `\dimexpr` (for example because you don't know the definition of the `p`-type column) you should put a `\relax` there to play safe.